# Logout takes too long

Tags: 14.10, logout

I'm using the greatful Ubuntu 14.10.

Sadly **logout takes about 1 minute and the cause is unknown**, as I installed most of my apps shortly after installed Ubuntu.
This slowdown happens since many days I'm using the system with an almost untouched configuration.

How can I investigate? Syslog is not showing any useful information.
My hardware is enough powerful to hold my cargo of apps, I never had a lag.

I've reported debug info related to the last logout process.

---

Thanks to @Takkat now I was able to do a test by typing in terminal *ps -aux | grep simone98rc*

---

System booted up:

```
root     11975  2.6  0.0  15036  3812 ?        Ds   18:22   1:55 /sbin/mount.ntfs /dev/sdc1 /media/simone98rc/SIMONE98RC -o rw,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177,uhelper=udisks2
simone9+ 23257  0.0  0.0  17208  3588 ?        S    19:27   0:00 bash /home/simone98rc/.steam/steam.sh
simone9+ 23289  0.9  0.1 643004 13944 ?        Sl   19:27   0:03 conky -c /home/simone98rc/.conky/Conky Seamod/conky_seamod
simone9+ 23441  1.4  2.0 336596 168960 ?       Sl   19:27   0:05 /home/simone98rc/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam
simone9+ 23456  0.0  0.8 135224 65916 ?        S    19:27   0:00 /home/simone98rc/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam
simone9+ 23457  0.0  0.0   4448   800 ?        S    19:27   0:00 sh -c "/home/simone98rc/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steamwebhelper" -cefhost -cachedir "config/htmlcache" -cookiepath "config/cookies" -steampid 23441 --blacklist-accelerated-compositing --process-per-tab
simone9+ 23458  0.3  0.5 336832 46456 ?        Sl   19:27   0:01 /home/simone98rc/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steamwebhelper -cefhost -cachedir config/htmlcache -cookiepath config/cookies -steampid 23441 --blacklist-accelerated-compositing --process-per-tab
simone9+ 23459  0.0  0.1 116360 15652 ?        S    19:27   0:00 /home/simone98rc/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steamwebhelper -cefhost -cachedir config/htmlcache -cookiepath config/cookies -steampid 23441 --blacklist-accelerated-compositing --process-per-tab
simone9+ 23460  0.0  0.2 113216 24220 ?        S    19:27   0:00 /home/simone98rc/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steamwebhelper --type=zygote --no-sandbox --lang=en_US.UTF-8 --product-version=Valve Steam Client
simone9+ 23778  0.7  0.7 758748 57460 ?        Sl   19:30   0:01 gedit /home/simone98rc/debug
simone9+ 24169  0.0  0.0  13692  2096 pts/1    S+   19:33   0:00 grep --color=auto simone98rc
```

During 1st logout:

```
simone9+  3812  1.0  0.1 643280 14216 ?        Sl   18:35   0:30 conky -c /home/simone98rc/.conky/Conky Seamod/conky_seamod
root     11975  1.6  0.0  15032  3812 ?        Ss   18:22   1:03 /sbin/mount.ntfs /dev/sdc1 /media/simone98rc/SIMONE98RC -o rw,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177,uhelper=udisks2
simone9+ 21569  0.0  0.0  13692  2100 pts/1    S+   19:25   0:00 grep --color=auto simone98rc
```

During 2nd logout:

```
root     11975  2.8  0.0  15184  3812 ?        Ss   18:22   2:17 /sbin/mount.ntfs /dev/sdc1 /media/simone98rc/SIMONE98RC -o rw,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177,uhelper=udisks2
simone9+ 25425  0.8  0.1 642924 13756 ?        Sl   19:39   0:00 conky -c /home/simone98rc/.conky/Conky Seamod/conky_seamod
simone9+ 26160  0.0  0.0  13692  2160 pts/4    S+   19:41   0:00 grep --color=auto simone98rc
```

---

Auth.log during logout

```
Nov 11 20:19:15 S98RC-UBUNTU polkitd(authority=local): Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-session:c2 (system bus name :1.92, object path /org/gnome/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale it_IT.UTF-8) (disconnected from bus)
Nov 11 20:20:46 S98RC-UBUNTU gnome-keyring-daemon[5805]: g_dbus_connection_real_closed: Remote peer vanished with error: Underlying GIOStream returned 0 bytes on an async read (g-io-error-quark, 0). Exiting.
Nov 11 20:20:46 S98RC-UBUNTU lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm:session): session closed for user simone98rc
```

Syslog during logout

```
Nov 11 20:19:36 S98RC-UBUNTU signond[16713]: ../../../../src/signond/signondaemon.cpp 388 init Failed to SUID root. Secure storage will not be available.
```

---

Now I need your opinions about.

Comment: possible duplicate (but not answered) https://askubuntu.com/questions/145573/logout-shutdown-taking-very-long-how-to-find-the-problem

Comment: @Takkat my terminal doesn't support your specified command. I typed "ps |grep -aux simone98rc".

Comment: @michael_n I'm using the default Unity dekstop environment, but the topic is similar to mine.

Comment: @Takkat I answered you in the topic question. I fear your user tag wasn't properly added by text editor, so I writed here again ;)

Comment: Not enough for me to give you an answer but it appears possible that Conky may be in the way of your logout. Only after a timeout logout will then succeed. Try to test a logout without Conky running to see if that resolved the logout issue.

Comment: When in TTY you may also try if `sudo killall conky` will lead you back to the login screen.

Comment: @Takkat sadly Conky is innocent, I continue to have an enervating logout time.
I obtanied less and probably better data from syslog and auth.log, I'll post them in my answer.
As seems, you are the only who can help me.

Comment: Sorry but it is a bit confusing for me too. Your NTFS drive may be another canidate to be in the way. Try to unmount it (Nautilus right click on the drive then *Unmount*) and see if the logout will then be faster.

Comment: I already tried to unmount as user my external hard disk before doing logout, but I waited the same long time :-(

Comment: I'm experiencing slow logout on Ubunbu Xenial 16.04 LTS as well. **Update**: but if I quit all apps before logging out, it is instantaneous.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are running steam.  I am also running steam on 14.04 LTS and only see the issue you are seeing when steam is running.  My guess is you have steam auto start?

If you manually exit steam (right click on it in the panel and Exit), then your logout will happen normally.

Comment: Thanks, I can confirm this was causing the issue for me. Is this issue documented somewhere on steam or did you find out by chance?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Go to terminal and type

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub
```

It will open the grub configuration file. Change the line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" acpi=force apm=power_off
```

and close it after saving.

Step 2: Again hit the terminal and type

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/modules
```

Type `apm power_off=1` below `lp` and save the file.

Step 3: Next type in the terminal

```
sudo update-grub
```

Once done with the above steps restart the machine.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force apm=power_off"` (all between quotation marks)?

Comment: Are you sure that I need to disable acpi/apm driver?
I'm sure that the OS is fully working, otherwise I would have a slow logout since fresh installation.
I want to prevent workarounds, especially when I'm the only unlucky user encountering the issues.

Thanks likewise :)